# How can I clear tmux history in all panes

Tags: tmux

I'm using `tmux clear-history` to clear the screen history. But it only works for the current pane, how can I do that for all available panes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to just run the clear-history on each pane

```
for pane in $(tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_id}'); do
  tmux clear-history -t "${pane}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmux list-panes -s | sed 's/:.*//g' | xargs -n 1 tmux clear-history -t
```

This will clear all panes on all windows.